# Remover truncated word at end of line via regex

Tags: python, regex

I have text which sometimes has the start of a particular word [e.g. `TRUNCATED`] at the end that I want to remove. For example:

```
 foo bar TRUNC
 bar foo TRUNCATED
 foo bar bar TRU
 foo
 foo bar bar bar TRUNCA
```

How would i remove this via regex - i assume there must be a better way than:

```
 corrected = re.sub(r" (T|TR|TRU|TRUN|TRUNC|TRUNCA|TRUNCAT|TRUNCATE|TRUNCATED)$", "", original)
```

[n.b. in case it is relevant, the truncation position is not consistent - i.e. sometimes it is truncated from the 20'th character, other times longer].

Comment: [`str = re.sub(' T(R(U(N(C(A(T(E(D)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$', '', str);`](https://regex101.com/r/uI1gF2/1)

Comment: Assuming the file isn't full of 'foo' and 'bar' strings (in which case it would be easy to solve anyway), how do you know that ' T' (or ' TR', or ' TRU') should be removed and is not something that occurs in the rest of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
T(R(U(N(C(A(T(ED?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

code:

```
 corrected = re.sub(r" (T(R(U(N(C(A(T(ED?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)$", "", original)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do in regex? Just do

```
s = "foo TRU"
l = s.rsplit(" ", 1)   # gives "foo" as long as TRUwhatever is the last word
final = l[0] if len(l) == 2 and l[1].startswith("T") else s
```

Comment: thanks - but it's only sometimes that there is a word at the end [and although could e.g. then check every word whether in list of possible matches, that starts to get complicated]

Comment: Well, thats not a problem.If the word is `"foo"` it will return `"foo"`.